# Flutter firebase phoneAuth issue

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter, dart

I'm using phone auth for authentication in flutter using firebase. But the autoVerify part is not getting successfully verified. In debug console it's showing verified but on firebase console there's no uid for the registered user . The following part creates the issue.

```
final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted = (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
    print('verified');

}
```

User is not getting registered because of this issue.

Can someone help me with this issue ?

Comment: need a snapshot of your logcat.

Comment: Please see it below

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should continue with signing in with credentials to complete the process. User should be showed up in Firebase Console after that.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
```

Comment: E/flutter (15264): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(FirebaseException, An internal error has occurred. [ DEVELOPMENT_MODE_MISMATCH:Development mode Verification Proof in non-development mode request. ], null)

Comment: I'm getting the above exception when I use FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

Comment: Have you enabled phone auth and added test phone numbers in Firebase Console?

Comment: Yes it is enabled . This exception throws up only when the firebase automatically verifies the number without having to type the incoming otp.

Comment: Are you in release mode? If so this whitelisted phone numbers in the console might be casuing this.

Comment: I'm in debug mode only .

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }